# Android Deeplink opens application twice

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, deep-linking

i used webview to create app and implemented deep linking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ariagp.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="mysitename.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

it will asking my for open with my application before open the links, but **the problem is**:
two applications will open in the phone task manager (**the application does not open in the previous application** which is running):

[image]

what is the solution?

Comment: Are they both opening when you click the deep link or you have one running in the background? Also, it the app opening in the app that the deep link was in?

Comment: yes, i have running the main app in background for testing, and then i will click in a link which shared in messages (you can see the messages icon in second application). Unfortunately the deep link will open From the source where it was clicked (for example whats app or messages application)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in declared activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

And then, in your activity, you should override `onNewIntent()` method and you will get arguments there.

Comment: thank you very much bro. it worked. can you solve this problem too??
question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309858/how-to-open-deep-links-in-webview-application]

Answer (score -2):

Ok, so you don't actually have a problem here.
This is just how deep links work. If you open one in a certain app, the deep link will open your app but in the same window the deep link was originally in.
Your app will have two instances in a way.

You could go to you web brower app and click share and any app that pops up. They all open in the web browsing app window. So there is nothing to worry about. I had the same problem myself before I realised that it is just how things work.

Some apps are just verified to open other apps if they implement the browsability.

Comment: But I have seen applications that open within themselves by clicking on the deep link. How are these implemented?

Comment: To my knowledge, it only depends on the app youre opening the hyperlink in. Because youre hyperlink start with http it is automatically matched with the browser app which supports links that start with http. You could try changing the scheme to yourapp:// instead of http, because that way the browser wont match with the hyperlink