# How to open Deep Links in webview application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, deep-linking

i have created my webview application and i loaded my main url in onCreate method to webview. then i implemented the deep links like this:

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ariagp.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="mysitename.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Now when the deep links get clicked, **the app will open on the webview homepage**.
But I want to make the **page related to the deep link** open.

And when the app itself opens, make the home page open.
what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the activity is launched, in the `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` method, get data from `intent` (it is supposed to be the url clicked - deep link) which has the type `uri`, and then load that url in the web view that you've implemented.

Something like below code:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Uri data = intent.getData();
        
    webView.loadUrl(data.toString());
}
```